# "According to smartctl, there's nothing wrong with this drive." appearing on system shutdown

Tags: 22.04, disk

I installed a fresh copy of Kubuntu 22.04 on a brand new 500Gb PNY CS900 SSD. I've been noticing a bunch of the following errors on system shutdown, and they're a bit worrying:

```
...Apr 22 15:34:07 sluggo kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 110924048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 17 prio class 0...

According to smartctl, there's nothing wrong with this
drive.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       527
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0003   087   087   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       63
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       131075
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0023   067   067   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       33 (Min/Max 33/33)
218 Unknown_Attribute       0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
231 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       99
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       354

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

What is going on here?

Comment: During shutdown of the machine I noticed them scroll by, so I went back and did a journalctl -b and scrolled down to see the item I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

`smartctl` monitors the [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology) status of your hard drives.

There aren't any errors here. The output tells you:

```
According to smartctl, there's nothing wrong with this 
drive.
```

So unless you're encountering an actual problem, this is a non-issue and your drive health is fine.

Comment: Thanks.. Glad its a non-issue as I'm not seeing any drive-related problems.